# Create Table in LaTeX (special case)

Tags: tables, wrap, border

Is it possible to create this table, page a4?

Difficult parts are border, wrap and cell size.
[image: Table created in Excel]

```
\begin{tabular}{r|lllll|}
    \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                    >& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2005}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2007}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2010}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{2012}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{Global Electricity Consumption (Million MWh)}}              & 1                             & 6                             & 7                             & 12                             & 13                              \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{Global Data Center Electricity Use (Million MWh)}}          & 2                             & 5                            & 8                             & 11                            & 14                                \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{Data Center as Fraction of Global Electricity Consumption}} & 3\%                            & 4\%                            & 9\%                            & 10\%                            & 15\%                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: By wrap, do you mean that the text in first column breaks over two lines?

Comment: Do the lines that border the cells have to be doubled?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, like in excel, if to make cell width small (to make the whole table within a page)

Comment: @Mico That'll look cool. Really want to play with borders in latex

Comment: @Mr.EU Just my personal opinion, but all these double lines are a bit too much. You might find https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf interesting to read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest to what you like to obtain:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,mdwtab,hhline}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\bfseries}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vline[1pt]}R{44ex}||c|c| c|c| c !{\vline[1pt]}}
    \cline[1pt]{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c||}{}
    & \textbf{2000} & \textbf{2005} & \textbf{2007} 
            & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2012}         \\ \hhline{=::=====}
Global Electricity Consumption (Million MWh)              
    &   1   &   6   &   7   &   12  &   13          \\ \hhline{-||-----}
Global Data Center Electricity Use (Million MWh)         
    &   2   &   5   &   8   &   11  &   14          \\ \hhline{-||-----}
Data Center as Fraction of Global Electricity Consumption 
    & 3\%   & 4\%   & 9\%   & 10\%  & 15\%          \\ \hhline{-||-----}
    \hlx[1pt]{h}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in above MWE I use `hhline` package for double lines (personaly I wouldn't use them also not all vertical lines) and good old `mdwtab` (which is not compatible with `colortbl`).

An alternative, to my taste more professional look you can obtain by use of `booktabs` and `tabularx` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\bfseries}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}R cc cc c}
    \cmidrule[1pt]{2-6}
    & \textbf{2000} & \textbf{2005} & \textbf{2007} 
            & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2012}         \\ \midrule
Global Electricity Consumption (Million MWh)              
    &   1   &   6   &   7   &   12  &   13          \\ %\hhline{-||-----}
Global Data Center Electricity Use (Million MWh)         
    &   2   &   5   &   8   &   11  &   14          \\ %\hhline{-||-----}
Data Center as Fraction of Global Electricity Consumption 
    & 3\%   & 4\%   & 9\%   & 10\%  & 15\%          \\ %\hhline{-||-----}
    \bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) for the `booktabs` solution. This looks so much better!

Comment: yea. It is really terrible, when people try to mimic a design of `excel` tables and their fancy borders in LaTeX.